# What does a ski jump takeoff feel like?

Tags: takeoff, aircraft-carrier

Some aircraft takeoff from aircraft carriers using a [ski jump](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27584/how-does-the-ski-shape-of-an-aircraft-carrier-deck-help-for-take-off).  What does it feel like to takeoff this way?  Does it feel like an alpine ski jump?  How does the feeling compare to catapult takeoff?

Comment: "feel" could be objectively measured with an accelarometer.

Comment: If I provided you with a plot of acceleration against time would it tell you what it feels like? If I told you it's like an alpine ski jump, but you've never done an alpine ski jump, would that tell you how it feels? I don't think this question is answerable in its current form.

Comment: Asking for a qualitative description is not the same as asking for an opinion. VTLO.

Comment: You will have a hard time finding anyone who has done both.

Comment: @CatchAsCatchCan "f I provided you with a plot of acceleration against time would it tell you what it feels like?" Me, yes.  Other people, maybe not.  "but you've never done an alpine ski jump" Well, I have, so this does not apply.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist while we try to answer the question for the benefit of the asker, the aim of any SE site is to provide knowledge to as many people as possible in a format accessible to everyone.

Comment: @Federico I did not wish to dictate the format of the answer.  If someone posts an overly technical answer, I can help make it more accessible.  The point I was making is that "what does takeoff feel like" is not opinion-based.

Comment: Go grab a skateboard, head to the nearest skate park and ride it at high speed off one of the ramps.

Comment: It's exactly like an alpine ski jump except instead of coming down and landing right away, you keep going. Hopefully. :)